# Is there a way to apply a transformation across preexisting keyframes?

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

I'm working on a modification of a preexisting weapon model's animations for a game mod, and need to make adjustments to the animations for the swapped model. What I essentially need to do is move one bone and then apply that transformation throughout all of the keyframes in the animation.

[image: The original]

[image: What I need]

The obvious way to go about this would be to go through every key frame in every animation and type out the transforms with precise values, but that's incredibly time consuming and seems a likely way for me to make mistakes.
Is there a way that I can perform one transformation, and then apply it to every other keyframe?

On a related note, is there a way I can align the camera to a bone's particular axis? If there's no way to perform a mass transform like this, it would at least eliminate a lot of potential for error by doing transformations by the view's orientation with consistent accuracy from frame to frame.

Comment: sounds like the autokeyframe button is your friend

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar problem right now. I cant seem to find a way to make "local" keyframe animations. Delta transforms aren't helpful either. E.g. I move a cube on the x-axis using 2 keyframes. Now I copy the cube, move and rotate it 90° using Delta Transforms. You would expect the copied cube now moves on the global y-axis, but it doesn't. It seems this is actually impossible using keyframes.

Comment: Use a child-of constraint on the bone (root?), targeting a new empty.  Adjust the empty to fit the new model.  Bake the action with visual keying + clear constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes can be created, read, updated and deleted.
Descriptions can be accurate or inaccurate.
From your description it leads the reader to believe you can delete all the keyframes for one particular bone and then create a single new keyframe or transformation.  If there are no keyframes the current transformation is the one that dominates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your problem emerged after you swapped the model, because you notice that with the old animation on the new model, the motions are a bit off?

I supposed something like that is an easy fix in graph editor, either that or add an offset animation to it using NLA editor.